# Why when playing mixamo animation on my player the player ending and also while playing the animation inside the ground(terrain)?

Tags: unity, c#

The player have this components : Animator , Rigidbody ,  Capsule Collider , Third Person User Control , Third Person Character.

I just downloaded mixamo animation for my character player.
In my Animator controller I added a new state and dragged in the animation.

Without the animation the player is standing fine.  but with the animation the player is inside the ground.

[image: The player is in the ground]

[image: The player animator controller settings in the inspector]

[image: The new state in the animator controller settings]

[image: The animation Rig tab settings --- I had to change it to be Humanoid to make the animation to be working correctly :]

Comment: Have u checked if the animation changes values relatively to 0 or to some other value? U can see the relative value in the first frame of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution is to check in enable true all the 3 Bake Into Pose. This did the trick

[image: Enabled true all the 3 Bake Into Pose]